# use existing autoscaling group name in terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-auto-scaling

I have a problem, i am trying to query the names of the existing autoscaling groups (i have 10 of them) and use that name to the autoscaling policy i have to create, all this has to be done using terraform also,  i have to do this automatically, because i have to use a terraform module for all that.

```
data "external" "eks_cluster_asg" {
  program = ["bash", "-c", <<EOT
    AWS_OUTPUT=\$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
      --query "AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key=='k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled'], 'true') && contains(Tags[?Key=='k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/cluster-name'], '${var.prefix}')].AutoScalingGroupName" \
      --output json \
      --region ${var.aws_region})
    echo "{\"autoscaling_group_name\": \"\${AWS_OUTPUT}\"}"
EOT
  ]
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "example" {
  autoscaling_group_name = jsondecode(data.external.eks_cluster_asg.result)["autoscaling_group_name"]
  policy_type           = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  name                  = "my-policy"

  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 70
  }
}
```

---

**Error:**

> invalid reference `echo "{\"autoscaling_group_name\": \"\${AWS_OUTPUT}\"}"` says a reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name

Comment: You forgot to explain what's exactly wrong with the current code. Any errors?

Comment: invalid reference 
echo "{\"autoscaling_group_name\": \"\${AWS_OUTPUT}\"}"
says a reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what do to?

Comment: i figured it out, it actually easy, but i did not pay attention
data "aws_autoscaling_groups" "eks_autoscaling_group" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:eks:cluster-name"
    values = [var.cluster-name]
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

You have to [escape](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences) `$` using `$$` as follows:

```
echo "{\"autoscaling_group_name\": \"\$${AWS_OUTPUT}\"}"
```